# Python ezdxf - Get outside dimensions and change orientation

Tags: python, ezdxf

I don't get the outer dimensions from the DXF.

```
import ezdxf as ez
import sys

doc = ez.readfile("T12706456-0.dxf")
msp = doc.modelspace()


# helper function
def print_entity(e):
    print("LINE on layer: %s\n" % e.dxf.layer)
    print("start point: %s\n" % e.dxf.start)
    print("end point: %s\n" % e.dxf.end)

# iterate over all entities in modelspace
msp = doc.modelspace()
for e in msp:
    if e.dxftype() == "LINE":
        print_entity(e)

# entity query for all LINE entities in modelspace
for e in msp.query("LINE"): 
    print_entity(e)
```

I don't get the outer dimensions from the DXF. I want if the DXF is in 'portrait' it will be converted to landscape. I also want to know the width and length of the DXF.

Answer (score 0):

Old question.  Offering this answer for anyone searching on this subject.

**"Outer dimensions"**
You need `ezdxf.bbox.entents` - [see this](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bbox.html) in the docs for limitations of what entities "count". For example, RAY and XLINE are ignored, of course, being of infinite length.

```py
import ezdxf
from ezdxf import bbox

doc = ezdxf.readfile("somedxf.dxf")
msp = doc.modelspace()

# extents of all qualifying model entities
limits = bbox.extents(msp.query("*")

# lower left and upper right coordinates of the extent:
limits.extmin, limits.extmax
```

The call to `bbox.extents` returns a `BoundingBox` object, [see the documentation](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/math/core.html#ezdxf.math.BoundingBox) for other useful attribs/methods.

**Orientation**
"Orientation" only has meaning when you plot or print the drawing. In CAD programs this is controlled by a dialog for print or plot settings, but this can be accessed in EZDXF by accessing the `DXFLayout` object of modelspace (or any paperspace layout)

```py
...
doc = ezdxf.readfile("somedxf.dxf")
msp = doc.modelspace()

plot_settings = msp.dxf_layout.dxfattribs()
```

This returns a dictionary of the plot settings, [listed here](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dxfobjects/plotsettings.html#plotsettings)
The setting that controls if the printer should print portrait or landscape is the attribute `plot_rotation`.  You may have to change other items in the plot configuration to get the expected results when printing out a DXF that has had its plot config altered by ezdxf.

The way I have used this in ezdxf code is to establish in a CAD program, an acceptable plot configuration geared to a specific layout, and read this out of a source DXF using the above command, then apply it to a target layout using `somelayout.update_dxf_attribs(dict_read_from_source)`

Hope this of some help to someone